# Python infinite for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm new to python and working through Euler problems to help learn it, and was able to solve problem 3 but it looks like I setup an infinite for loop but can't figure out where.

```
i = 2
j = 2
for i in range(1,600851475143):
    if 600851475143%i ==0:
        for j in range (2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
            else:
                j +=1
    if i==j:
        print(j)
i+=1
j=2
```

Comment: Could you format your code properly by wrapping it in triple backticks: ```

Comment: I have formatted the code block. For future reference if you highlight the whole code block and hit `ctrl-k` it will indent it as required to be formatted as code.

Comment: This isn't an infinite loop although it is a nested loop over a very high range so it may run for a long time. In general, if a project Euler problem takes more than a handful of seconds, there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thank you!